# Bootcamp Failing with Error: "The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition."

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, macos

I have a 21.5" Mid-2010 iMac i3 in which I am trying to install Windows 8 on. When I went into bootcamp, I received the ever so common error of:
[image: Bootcamp Error]
When I went to the newly designed disk utility, it told me I had one partition. Of course, I knew this couldn't be true, so i went into terminal and typed `diskutil list` and got:

**OLD COMMAND OUTPUT, SEE EDIT 2 BELOW**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            498.6 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s6
   4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s5
```

Now, I did install an extra Yosemite partition, then deleted it using standard disk utility erase. I'm guessing thats why I have *two* recovery partitions. Now, I'm pretty sure this is the cause of the Bootcamp issue, but I want to know:

1. Which partition to delete
2. How to delete it in a (preferably  safe) way that would make my hard disk "clean" of everything but my main Macintosh HD partition

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I want to delete the extra recovery partition from my second installation of Yosemite.

Running `sudo gpt-r show /dev/disk0` gave me:

**OLD COMMAND OUTPUT, SEE EDIT 2 BELOW**

```
          start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  973824416      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  974234056    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  975503592    1269536      4  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  976773128          7         
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

**EDIT 2:**
Reran the two commands:

```
    iMac-i3:~ me$ diskutil list /dev/disk0
    /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
       2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            498.6 GB   disk0s2
       3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
       4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4

    iMac-i3:~ me$ sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
    Password:
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  973824416      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  974234056    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  975503592    1269536      4  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  976773128          7         
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Your output from `diskutil` and `gpt` conflict with each other. The 5 and 6 from disk0s6 and disk0s5 need to be indices from the type 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC partitions, but you posted indices of 3 and 4. As far as I know, this is not possible. I don't know, maybe you need to restart the computer and try again.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I reran the commands and edited the question, and strangely, the recovery partition numbers changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Which partition to delete?

1. Restart your computer and hold down the alt/option key.
2. Select the recovery partition you wish to keep. For example, with El
   Captain OS X 10.11 installed, the recovery partition should be
   labeled "Recovery-10.11".
3. Once booted to this partition, select the Terminal application for
   the menu bar.
4. In the opened Terminal application window, enter the `mount`
   command. The partition you selected will show up in the list. The
   other recovery partition will be absent.

The absent partition is the one to delete.

### How to delete it in a (preferably safe) way that would make my hard disk "clean" of everything but my main Macintosh HD partition?

By "clean", I assume you mean you want to remove the extra Recovery HD partition.

If you want to remove `disk0s3` then you should first copy the contents of `disk0s4` to `disk0s3`. This can be down using the command given below.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s4 of=/dev/disk0s3 bs=16384
```

You will need to remove the 4th partition. Follow the steps below.

1. Start your computer from Internet Recovery. Press and hold the
   Command-Option+R keys immediately after you turn on your Mac and
   hear the startup sound. Your model is capable of using Internet
   Recovery, but your firmware may need to be updated. See [Computers
   that can be upgraded to use OS X Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313).

   Note: An alternative would be to startup using the Snow Leopard (OS
   X 10.6) or earlier DVD.
2. From the menu bar, open the Terminal application.
3. Enter the following commands in the Terminal application window.

   ```
   diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0
   gpt remove -i 4 /dev/disk0
   ```

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: @BobRon: I edited my answer.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I don't recommend the dd command. Just mount disk0s3 and disk0s4, cat | grep the product version and if the product version of disk0s3 is non equal to the product version of disk0s2 and disk0s4 and product version of disk0s2=disk0s4 then dd disk0s4 to disk0s3 and then delete disk0s4 with gpt. Otherwise just delete disk0s4.

Comment: @klanomath: Actually since the size of a Yosemite recovery partition is 1269536 and an El  Captain recover partition is 1269544, I assume both partitions are from Yosemite. No other words, he might as well keep the 3rd one and delete the 4th one.

Comment: @DavidAnderson On my 10.11 system the rp has also 1269536 blocks. So the size isn't specific.

Comment: @David Anderson This may be a different question, but when I boot into Internet Recovery, it downloads and then gets stuck on the Apple logo.

Comment: Never mind, I followed this [this](http://osxdaily.com/2011/06/30/deleting-the-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-recovery-hd-partition/) article and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my iMac 5K, I was trying to install windows via bootcamp but after trying several times (because of corrupt file), whenever I started the bootcamp I got that error. And also did not appear the partition of the operating system (8gb).

What I did to solve the situation was:

1 - put the windows.iso file in the same location where it was (in my case on the desktop)

2 - open the disk utility and erase the partition "bootcamp"

4 - unmount the partition "bootcamp"

5 - reopen the bootcamp, and do "restore"

3 - I'm not sure if I've formatted it, but if the previous steps doesn't work try this step too. Format the "bootcamp" partition in last option (ExFat I guess).

After having installed windows I discovered that the partition of the operating system was hidden, that is, everything was fine.

I hope you have solved :)