# startup disk cannot be partitioned

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I am trying to install windows 10 on my mid 2011 iMac with Bootcamp and when trying to partition my disk it's giving me this error:

> The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single
>   partition

- This is the output of `diskutil list`:
  [image: diskutil output]
- `diskutil cs list` outputs:

> No CoreStorage logical volume groups found

Can anyone please help me get windows 10 installed on my iMac and solve this problem?

Thanks so much and first time poster! Be gentle with me! Haha. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a very common question - look there: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344478/the-startup-disk-cannot-be-partitioned-or-restored-to-a-single-partition-window?rq=1 or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211121/bootcamp-failing-with-error-the-startup-disk-cannot-be-partitioned-or-restored?rq=1 or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352934/the-startup-disk-cannot-be-partitioned-or-restored-to-a-single-partition-window?rq=1 or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362945/bootcamp-error-the-startup-disk-cannot-be-partitioned-or-restored-to-a-single-p?rq=1

Comment: If you want to try and fix your existing problem, then boot to macOS Recovery and post the output from the command `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`.

Comment: You probably would be better off erasing the entire drive and starting over. Note: The easiest way to get Windows 10 is to first use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 7, then upgrade to Windows 10. Otherwise, the instructions for installing Windows 10 can be found at: [How to install Windows 10 into a 2011 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, an optical (DVD) drive or third party tools?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant/308812#308812).